# S4462 issue: Calls to "async" methods should not be blocking. How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, sonarqube, configureawait

I am trying to call an asynchronous method from a synchronous method.

For instance: Let `methodAsync` be an asynchronous method.

```
static void methodSync()
{
    object1.methodAsync().Wait();
    object1.methodAsync().Result;
    object1.methodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

*Suggestion by sonar:*

> Replace this use of `Task.Wait` with `await`.

Similarly, for the `Task.Result` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` .
https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4462

what can we do to call asynchronous method from a synchronous method?

Comment: It already tells you what to do. What question are you asking?

Comment: Replacing Task.Wait with await cannot be done as the methodSync()- the calling function, is a synchronous method trying to call an asnchronous method - methodAsync().
How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method?

Comment: Then you ignore the warning and move on.